# AWK Pass Variable to Command

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to pass $9 into my executed php command using awk.  However the $9 never makes it to the command.  If I manually establish the value for param1 everything works.

```
cat file.name | awk -v date="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")" '{
 x="'"`/usr/bin/php-cgi -f /path/hex2bin.php param1=$9`"'"
print "New value: ",$x
}'
```

Comment: OBJECTIVE: I want to be able to return the value from php file passing in parameter, make it a variable and later use that variable in my AWK for more execution.

Comment: You don't need the `cat file |` https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-badunixhabits.html#ten

Answer (score 2):

***1st point***:Though I am not php expert, I have seen usually shell commands run under `exec` command.

***2nd point:*** You need not to use `cat` with `awk`. `awk` could read any Input_file passed to it. eg--> `awk '........' Input_file`

***A try to fix your code:*** Since you have NOT mentioned why you are printing `x` variable again in `awk` program + why `date` is mentioned in variable but not being used?

What I am doing here is calling `php` script by passing `$9` with escaping `$` in it by `awk`'s `system` command(Without samples I am not able to run this command).

```
awk -v s1="'" -v s2="\"" -v date="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")" '
{
  system(s1 "/usr/bin/php-cgi -f /path/hex2bin.php param1= " s2 "$9" s1)
}'  Input_file
```

But 1 things is there using `system` command in `awk` you will be able to execute other/shell commands by it, since it is executing commands in another sub shell so you will NOT be able to take its output value into `awk` variable, experts could correct me if I missed something here.

***EDIT:*** Or try to use while loop itself.

```
while read line one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
do
   new_variable=$(your_php_command "$nine")
   echo "Use here new_variable...."
done < "Input_file"
```

Comment: OBJECTIVE: I want to be able to return the value from php file passing in parameter, make it a variable and later use that variable in my AWK for more execution.

Comment: Why don't you create shell script and then your php command there then pass that shell variable to awk script or use a while loop to read file by that you need not to get in puzzle to get back variables to awk etc.

Comment: I Just want to pass in $9 into the second line.  How can I do this using the ` logic?

Comment: @user1157800, I believe I had provided that solution to you and I mentioned already that if you use system command it may not be able to return you back values. I don't believe without system we could call it in `awk`.

Comment: @user1157800, try my EDIT command once too? It is only a guidance for you. You could write your php actual script there and could pass variable to it then, let me know?

Comment: I have to get variable from AWK and pass it to PHP script and get the results. Then use the results in a later variable for processing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185233/discussion-between-user1157800-and-ravindersingh13).